# Closest approximation to Python 2 style printing in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

What are options for keeping as close to the python2 way of printing.

```
>>> x1='hi'
>>> x2='there'
>>> print "Val1=%s Val2=%s" %(x1,x2)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "%s" %x
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It would not be necessary to mention : "lose your 'old' way of thinking and use the {} in python3."  I *am* aware of the "blessed" python3 syntax, and given it is not in my estimation preferable, would like to see what other options exist.

thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to use the language, don't use it. I don't. If you do want to use the language, then you have to use it as it is.

Comment: As shown below I did upvote two answers and accept one . It is possible  to use the language and generally like it (i do for python) and not prefer one or more of its constructs. Do you prefer every construct of the languages you use?

Comment: Python 2 and Python 3 are different languages. You could just stick with 2 if you prefer it.

Comment: @marcin There are requirements to use Python 3 in a class I attend. In addition my posting does not say (nor is it the case) that I dislike the entire python3 language. You are making incorrect assumptions not included in my post.

Comment: I'm not assuming anything. You're asking how to use python 2 syntax in python 3.

Comment: .. and you are exptrapolating that question to mean I dislike the entire python3 language. Which is incorrect.

Comment: I'm not extrapolating anything. If you don't want to use python 3 syntax, don't use python 3.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34082/discussion-between-javadba-and-marcin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is still valid syntax in python 3, but [print is no longer a statement](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function). It is a function, so you must put parentheses:

```
print("%s" % x)
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a space?

Comment: @user2357112 Wait, you don't? I can't test this; I'm on my phone. Thank you

Comment: Operators don't require spaces between them and their operands. `>>> 'a'in'abv'`
`True`

Answer (score 3):

None. Avoid `print`/`print()` entirely if you want perfect compatibility.

```
sys.stdout.write('%s\n' % (x,))
```

Comment: Hi Ignacio,  would you pls explain further:  what incompatibilities exist between the print() function and the sys.stdout.write?

Comment: Lots. But the change from a statement to a function is even larger.